# Reading and writing an array to file

Tags: java, android

Hello there stackoverflow .
The thing im tring to make work is saving some information from an array to a file and then reading it back to another array . The goal is to save themes (hex color codes of user) so they can share their theme or backing it up  . 
Here is my code to write the array to file

```
String filename = "my.theme";
String[] numbers = new String[] {"1, 2, 3"};
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    for (String s : numbers) {  
        outputStream.write(s.getBytes());  
    } 
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is a file with  :

```
1,2,3
```

Now how can i read it back to another array ?
For my goal . Can you suggest anything other then using this method ? Its ok to save as a xml too . Thanks :)

Comment: Did you search Google for "Java Read File To Array"? `Scanner`, `BufferedReader`, etc. come to mind.

Comment: If you are interested in saving the data as XML, have a look at JAXB. For an introduction: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Comment: @JonnyHenly nope i searched everythig expect that . Tnx

Comment: @Beethoven is it possible to read it back ? Thanks i will have a look

Comment: @NikanDalvand Yes it's for reading and writing.

Comment: @Beethoven ok thanks i will give it a try

Comment: Your array contains one string of `"1,2,3"`, by the way, not three individual number strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Scanner class, this small example will help you get started:

```
String input = "1,2,3";
Scanner scn = new Scanner(input);  // Scanner also accepts a file!
scn.useDelimiter(","); // Since the integers are "comma" separated.
while(scn.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(scn.nextInt()); // here you can store your integers back into your array
}
scn.close();
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: @cricket_007 the OP has already written to a file, and reading back can be done with a Scanner, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Ah, guess I missed the part that the file was already written

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you give me the file example ?
This one crashed my app ! 
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/"+ "theme.test";

Comment: Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ "theme.test"; and also don't forget to mention the read/write permissions in manifest.

Comment: @cricket_007 happens with everyone ;)

Comment: @SarthakMittal thanks for your help  . Yeah thats the first thing i added to my app

Comment: @NikanDalvand haha, anytime! happy coding!

Comment: @SarthakMittal sorry to bother you but it gives me inputmismatchepection . I think its the write part

Comment: @NikanDalvand i will have to see the code to resolve that.